# Error printing NSCFNumber cast as NSNumber using NSNumberFormatter and RestKit

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, restkit, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to print/access my (double) value from a JSON call and get:

[Event latitude]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d09970

When accessing a string value from the same object, it prints just fine.  In the debugger, I see my values and event.latitude is mapped as an NSCFNumber from a double.  I don't know if this is just me not casting or declaring latitude properly, or is something not mapping right for that value.  Strings work

Here is some code:

```
event.h
@interface Event : NSObject  {
    NSNumber    *latitude;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *latitude;
@end
```

ViewController.m snippet

```
Event *event = (Event *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

static NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter;
if (numberFormatter == nil) {
    numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
}
NSLog(@"Event - %@", event.name );  //This works just fine
NSLog(@"Event - %@", event.latitude );  //This is where I am testing different ways of accessing the latitude
NSLog(@"Event - %@", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[event latitude]] );
//NSLog(@"Event - %@", [[event latitude] stringValue] );
NSString *coordinatesString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Lat:%@, Lon:%@",
                               [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[event latitude]],
                               [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[event longitude]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's definitely not about casting.

The exception you're getting is due to the lack of a `latitude` implementation, that you probably forgot or mistyped.

Did you `@synthesize` the property in the `Event.m` implementation file?

Comment: You nailed it.  I had dynamic latitude;  and should have been synthesize.  The other attributes were synthesized.

Answer (score 0):

`[Event latitude]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d09970` means that the Event object did not have a method called "latitude".

I'd suggest you first check to be sure you spelled "latitude" correctly everywhere (you can look at that sort of thing five times and not see it sometimes), and that it's properly (un)capitalized.

After that I'd say you should make sure you don't have two different definitions of "Event" somehow.  You can create a test instance of Event and directly access the "latitude" property to be sure everything's OK.